# Low voltage landscape lighting

Tags: batteries, led

I install low voltage landscape lighting and I’m trying to make up some fixtures that I can run off of 8-AA batteries with like a battery holder (8-aa batteries with 2 wires coming out of holder)as a “demo lighting system” without having to drag out drop cords,transformers,wires,etc.

There is a product out already out that does this exact thing. It’s made by “king innovations” and it’s called the insta light.It says “When you purchase this device it comes with: Battery Pack/Housing, 12V LED Power Cord, and extension coupler.”

I just want to make sure that I don’t need any kind of converter or anything. I’m pretty sure I don’t, I mean it is 12 oh low-voltage and that’s exactly what eight AA batteries equals. If anyone has any input on how I can build something similar for myself, I would greatly appreciate the input. They are charging $40/fixture to light them up and I can get a battery holder with led power cord and connectors [image]

Answer (score 0):

If the lighting is designed to run on 12V, then a box of batteries adding up to 12V will work.  It's up to you to work out what adapters you need to actually wire the battery box to the lamps.  But it will only be a case of finding the right plugs or sockets.  And make sure you get the positive and negative the right way round.

That said, AA cells can deliver only a quite modest current.  Don't expect to floodlight an entire sports pitch off a few AA cells.